# Locking on String.Format()

Tags: c#, string, locking, format

I'm implementing caching in an asp.net mvc application and to prevent queries from running more than once when the cache is refreshed I'm using a lock around any database access code.

Since I have a unique cache key for each piece of data I think it might be a good idea to lock on that string. But sometimes the data that is to be fetched is unique to a specific user (e.g. all comments written by user X) so I'm using String.Format() to put the user's id into the cache key.

Here's an example:

```
    private const string cacheKey = "blog_comments_from_specific_user-{0}";

    private List<Comments> GetCommentsFromuser(int userId)
    {
        if (GetCache(String.Format(cacheKey, userId)) == null)
        {
            lock (String.Format(cacheKey, userId))
            {
                if (GetCache(String.Format(cacheKey, userId)) == null)
                {
                    // get data from database
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the database code to run only once for each unique string content but I'm not sure if that is what it is doing. I have not found a way to test it. I read that there is a String.Intern() method that would make it possible to lock on the specific string content but do I need that too or is String.Format() enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not lock on strings**. They have subtle behaviours (interning, app-domain reuse, unpredictable use in other locations) that make them inappropriate for this. If you want per-key locking, create a dictionary (or similar; `Hashtable` has better threading semantics, but is non-generic) of keys (strings) to lock objects (perhaps just `new object()`).

Comment: if I understand correctly, the dictionary would be used to map the keys to the objects used for the locking?would the dictionary need to be persisted in some way (globally for all users)? otherwise the dictionary would only ever contain one set (key and object) as this code is inside a model of an mvc application that briefly exists for each user to extract the data

Comment: @Vik indeed the dictionary would be shared between all requests. It does not need to be persisted though: mvc apps don't exist per-request - they are deeply concurrent, with an app-domain spanning many many requests

Comment: The model instance itself exists per-request though if I've not misunderstood. Would the dictionary be shared between requests as a static member of the model class?

Answer (score 0):

`String.Format` does not necessarily return the same object, even if two Strings match:

```
var str1 = String.Format("{0}{1}", 1, 2);
var str2 = String.Format("{0}{1}", 1, 2);
Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2);
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2));
```

Because of that, locking on one instance of such a string will not correctly synchronize with a lock on another instance. One way to fix that is to use the .NET's mechanism of [String interning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx). See the following example:

```
var str3 = String.Intern(String.Format("{0}{1}", 1, 2));
var str4 = String.Intern(String.Format("{0}{1}", 1, 2));
Console.WriteLine(str3 == str4);
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(str3, str4));
```

The other way, as already mentioned, is to have a separate collection of lock objects that are uniquely assigned to each String.